# Diophantine equation with cubes.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Interested in the solution in general Diophantine equations of the form:

$X^3+Y^3+Z^3=3XYZ+q$

$q$ - what some integer.

Solutions similar equations can be written.

Since this equation is easy, as it is quite symmetrical.

$X^3+Y^3+Z^3-3XYZ=R^3$

Such a solution can write.

$X=sp(p+s)$

$Y=s(2p^2+s^2)$

$Z=p(p^2+2s^2)$

$R=p^3+s^3$

And solutions can be written:

$X=s(9p^2+9ps+10s^2)$

$Y=s(6p^2+12ps+7s^2)$

$Z=3p^3+3p^2s+15ps^2+7s^3$

$R=3(p+2s)(p^2-ps+s^2)$

Whether there are any thoughts how to solve this equation?

At first I thought to use for solving Pell's equation, but I think that you can do without.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following identity:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)$$

Fixed integer q has a finite number of factorial expansions. So we get a finite number of systems of two equations:

$$x+y+z = a$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz = b$$

for all integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ab=q$. Excluding the variable z we obtain the quadratic equation in x and y.

CALCULATIONS:

Let $u = x + y$ and $v=x y$. Then we have $z = a - u$ and
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz = u^2 - 2v + (a-u)^2 - v - (a-u)u =$$
$$u^2 - 3v + a^2 - 2au + u^2 - au +u^2 = 3u^2 - 3au - 3v + a^2$$

Thus, we have a equation in integers u and v:
$$ 3(u^2 - au) - 3v = b - a^2$$ 
It`s something like [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) as you said. But it is more simple and we can express v from u:

$$ 3v = 3(u^2 - au) - (b - a^2)$$

Next step. Let suppose that (x,y) is an integer solution of original equation then because $u = x + y$ and $v=x y$ there is integer m such that $u^2-4v=m^2$ (this is a discriminant of a square equation $(\lambda - x)(\lambda - y) = \lambda^2-u\lambda+v=0$).

So $4v = u^2 - m^2$ and we have the following transformations of the equation:
$$ 3v = 3(u^2 - au) - (b - a^2)$$
$$12(u^2 - au)-3*4v = 4(b-a^2)$$
$$12(u^2 - au)-3(u^2-m^2)=4(b-a^2)$$
$$9u^2 - 12au + 3m^2=4(b-a^2)$$
$$9u^2 - 12au + 4a^2 + 3m^2=4b$$
$$(3u-2a)^2 + 3m^2=4b$$

Thus, we have that the number of solution for each fixed a and b is finite! So for each parameter q we can find all solutions (x,y,z) of the original equation $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 3xyz + q$ by the following formulas:

$$x=\frac{u-m}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{u+m}{2}$$
$$z=a-u$$

where u and m form a solution of the equation:

$$(3u-2a)^2 + 3m^2=4b$$

Comment: I talked about it, and in his post. Solving this system of equations I come to Pell's equation. Thanks anyway. I'll think about how to do without it.

Comment: You can make further restrictions on $b$: given $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2b$ we know that $b$ is not of the form $2^{2k+1}(8m+7)$.

Comment: After writing this you actually say that for a given number $q$ - number of solutions of course, but it is not. The number of solutions is infinite. And in general. What a way to bring solutions - without writing formulas of their decisions?

Comment: I am calculate and as you said, individ, get something like Pell's equation :)

Comment: Good for you. One does not solve the equation changed to another. In number theory, such manner of calculation.  So solve the equation, so it is not addressed. The equation is solved - this is when the formula is written receipt of the decision without further action.

Comment: I find that this last equation more simple than Pell`s

Comment: Incorrect calculation. $u,v$ - different functions depending on the same variables. so they depend on each other. In solving this system still come to Pella. All these calculations still need to create another equation to solve. One equation is replaced by another.

Comment: Yes-yes, you are right, I know. I think now how to invert integers values u and v to x and y. Maybe in the number theory exists recipes because we need only find counter images for a simple map: u = x + y, v = x * y.

Comment: I do not think there is a sense of the conversation. How to watch - Destinations decision yet.

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake the set of solutions of the equation is finite!

Comment: No. Infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Not everything is correct. The last equation has a solution for $q=ab=3*31$ : $u=7$ : $m=3$ so $x=2$ ; $y=5$ ; $z=-4$ Solution does not work. I do not understand why I was one equation to another? If the equation is solved, it should turn out formula. I understand that in the theory of numbers is such a common practice, but this should get rid.

Comment: Formula written.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I find small error in signs and edit formulas.

Comment: No. The formula should look like I wrote. Your wrong.

Comment: No you are not right!!! It's exactly the same formula! I just check. k = 3u-2a, t = m.

Comment: Saw the corrected version. It turns out one formula. Next replacement $4v=u^2-m^2$ obtained artificially, but it should appear in the course of solving the equation. During the decision should be clearly seen that only with such a solution is possible representation. And so then the question arises - can substitute for another when $v$ - may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, the solution is finite.

for the equation:

$X^3+Y^3+Z^3-3XYZ=q=ab$

If it is possible to decompose the coefficient as follows:

$4b=k^2+3t^2$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$X=\frac{1}{6}(2a-3t\pm{k})$

$Y=\frac{1}{6}(2a+3t\pm{k})$

$Z=\frac{1}{3}(a\mp{k})$

Thought the solution is determined by the equation Pell, but when calculating the sign was a mistake. There's no difference, but the amount should be. Therefore, the number of solutions of course.